# Accessing GPIO Pins on Linux Embedded Running on a Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: embedded-linux, raspberry-pi3, yocto, yocto-recipe

I am trying to currently make a c program that will make a light blink on a Raspberry Pi 3 with embedded linux installed. I am currently building the image for the OS using yocto, poky with the raspberry pi 3 and open embedded. The OS installs on the SD card and I can have managed to add the layer that runs applications and have made a simple hello world. I am now trying to access the GPIO pins but having trouble with this.

Comment: "*There isn't many resources on this topic online.*" -- Really?  What did you search for?  You need to try again.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of resources that talk about `blink LED on Raspberry`.

Check [here](https://www.admfactory.com/blinking-led-on-raspberry-pi-using-c/), [here](https://startingelectronics.org/software/raspberry-PI/raspberry-PI-flash-LED-C/), [here](https://www.kompulsa.com/raspberry-pi-gpio-tutorial-how-to-blink-an-led-on-the-raspberry-pi-3/), or [here](https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-blink-an-led-on-raspberry-pi-3-model-b/)

Your question is related to `Yocto`, because once you constructed the image and boot it correctly, you just need to know how to develop a `userspace` example to control your desired `GPIO`.

- **NOTES**:

You may encounter that `GPIO` is not exported in `userspace`, so check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54376072/how-do-i-enable-the-sysfs-export-gpio-number-from-userspace-support-for-linux).